# My automation is successful even if there is no file placed in FTP

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, automation, sftp

How can my automation be successful even when there is no file placed in SFTP? I have created a support ticket to confirm if there is blank file processing feature enabled, Support replied that this feature is off. In this situation how can this automation be successful. Any inputs here are helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Please make sure to tag your questions as `marketing-cloud` for increased visibility

Comment: You need to be more specific. A file drop trigger will never fire, if no file is placed. Are you sure you are monitoring the right folder? What about file naming pattern in trigger vs file import activity? You give us  no details to work with. Hence providing you with any useful help is close to impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe when I created a support ticket, the team mentioned that there is a data retention for which the already placed file was being picked up when there is no file, when the retention was over, and file was deleted from FTP the automation started being unsuccessful. Yes, to answer your question, I have also checked my file naming pattern, it was the right folder etc. Still, I was clueless. But I think I got my answer for this concern. Thanks!